# importing csv into R with empty factors and missing factor levels

Tags: r, csv, factors

I have a data set with Scores and Categories in a csv file

```
VAR1_SCORE  VAR1_CAT    VAR2_SCORE  VAR2_CAT    VAR3_SCORE  VAR3_CAT 
80          MID         60         LOW      
80          MID         100        HIGH 
90          HIGH        90         HIGH
```

I am reading a csv file in above format.
Please note*: VAR1_CAT doesn't have LOW LEVEL DEFINED

While importing I want to achieve,

1. define same factor levels for all category contains('_cat')
2. there could be empty variables like VAR3_scores. This should be read-in as numerical and not logical
3. the empty variable (VAR3_CAT / VAR1_CAT) should have same factor levels (HIGH - MID -LOW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the data with `read.csv` for instance, then use some `tidyverse` afterwards

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("CAT")), ~factor(., levels = c("LOW", "MID", "HIGH")))
```

Show the levels:

```
select(df, ends_with("CAT")) %>% 
  map(levels)
$VAR1_CAT
[1] "LOW"  "MID"  "HIGH"

$VAR2_CAT
[1] "LOW"  "MID"  "HIGH"

$VAR3_CAT
[1] "LOW"  "MID"  "HIGH"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
         mutate(across(ends_with('CAT'), factor, levels = c("LOW", "MID", "HIGH")))
```